# How do I filter latest app-engine version from all of the versions using gcloud command or any bash script

Tags: bash, shell, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to make a bash script which will delete 30 days older Google App Engine version, already made it and its working fine. But now my concern is if latest app-engine service version itself 30 days old, then it will delete also. How can I prevent this if in app-engine only have the latest version, then it will not fire the command of `gcloud app versions delete $VERSION --service $1 -q` else it will delete 30 days older version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by TRAFFIC_SPLIT and delete only the versions that do not have traffic allocation or any Boolean condition that you want to create:

For example this command will print all the versions with traffic split == 0:

```
for row in `gcloud app versions list --filter="traffic_split=0" --format="table(version.id)"| tail -n +2`; do echo  $row; done
```

Or all versions with serving_status == stopped

```
for row in `gcloud app versions list --filter="serving_status=stopped" --format="table(version.id)"| tail -n +2`; do echo  $row; done
```

Then inside the for loop you can delete the version that you want:

```
do gcloud app versions delete $row --quiet
```

Comment: can we use two filter parameter like --filter="traffic_split=0" & --filter="version.createTime.date('%Y-%m-%d', Z)<'$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="25 days ago")'" in gcloud app versions list command

Comment: You can use something like this: --filter="trafic_split=0 AND version.createTime.date('%Y-%m-%d', Z)<'$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="25 days ago"

Comment: `gcloud app versions list --service name --filter="traffic_split=0" --filter="version.createTime.date('%Y-%m-%d', Z)<'$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="10 days ago")'" --format="table(version.id)"| tail -n +2` it's only use the time filter not the traffic filter.

Comment: I think it should  be only one --filter="bool1 AND bool2 AND bool3"  [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--hide-no-traffic` flag to list versions that are receiving traffic and skip deleting these versions.

```
  $ gcloud app versions list --hide-no-traffic
```

Comment: I believe he'd actually need the opposite and **not** delete versions that currently receive traffic

Comment: Yes, thats what i suggested.  --hide-no-traffic will give the list of instances that are receiving traffic and they can skipped from deletion.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing. Let me edit the answer. Thanks @LundinCast

Comment: Actually I want to filter 25 days older versions which is not serving the traffic. `--filter="traffic_split=0"` that filter is working but when I try to use with `gcloud app versions list --service name --filter="traffic_split=0" --filter="version.createTime.date('%Y-%m-%d', Z)<'$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="10 days ago")'" --format="table(version.id)"| tail -n +2` it will work only the time filter not the traffic filter.

Comment: What happen if you use: --filter="traffic_split=0" AND "version.createTime.date('%Y-%m-%d', Z)<'$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="10 days ago")'". Only one --filter with two Boolean condition using AND